# Android Camera Image Rotate Issue

Tags: android

I have the image rotate problem.  All the solutions I have found are outdated. The closest I have got is following [How to get uri of captured photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448297/how-to-get-uri-of-captured-photo) to get the uri.
If I include the line
takePicture.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)
then I do not get resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK.
If I run with the line in then I get a crash at val ei = ExifInterface(uri.toString()).
Also .getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated and I can't find what I am supposed to be using.

```
class SelImageDialogFragment: DialogFragment() {

    var useCamera: Int = 0
    var useGallery: Int = 0
    private val options = arrayOf("Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel")

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            builder.setTitle("Choose profile picture")
            builder.setItems(options) { dialog, item ->
                if (options[item] == options[0]) {
                    val takePicture = Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                    val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyPhoto.jpg")
                    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MyApp.applicationContext(), MyApp.applicationContext().packageName + ".provider", file)
                    takePicture.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)
                    activity!!.startActivityForResult(takePicture, useCamera)
                } else if (options[item] == options[1]) {
                    val pickPhoto = Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                    )
                    activity!!.startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, useGallery)
                } else if (options[item] == options[2]) {
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
            }
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }
}


if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    val imageBitmap = data.extras?.get("data")
                    val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyPhoto.jpg")
                    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", file)
                    val ei = ExifInterface(uri.toString())
                    val orientation = ei.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                    when (orientation) {
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90.toString() -> {
                            println("NOTE orientation 90 out")
                        }
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180.toString() -> {
                            println("NOTE orientation 180 out")
                        }
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270.toString() -> {
                            println("NOTE orientation 270 out")
                        }
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL.toString() -> {
                            println("NOTE orientation normal")
                        }
                    }

                    binding.profileImg.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap as Bitmap?)
                    if (imageBitmap != null) {
                        encodeBitmapAndSaveToFirebase(imageBitmap)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Post the logcat so we know why your app crashes.

Comment: If you have a File instance then you do not need to make an uri for it to present to ExifInterface. ExifInterface can handle the File instance directly. Also use File.exists() before using ExifInterface.

Comment: How can you talk about a rotate issue when your app crashes?

Comment: Refer to this answer I posted yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271736/take-a-photo-and-saving-it-in-full-size/72362209#72362209